# Python - OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive:

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, file-transfer

I'm using

```
os.rename()
```

to try to move pdf files between drives.  Attempting this I receive the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive
```

Is anyone aware of a function which contains similar functionality to `os.rename` and allows for across disk file transfer?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`os.rename()` change the path of the file but doesn't move its actual data on the disk.
this is why you can't move (rename) it from one drive to another.

moving between drives is actually copy it first, and then delete the source file.
you can use `shutil.move()` method which do it when you trying to transfer files between two drives

```
import shutil
shutil.move(src, dest)
```