# os.rename error - The system cannot move the file to a different disk

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a GUI for the program that renames all the files numerically (eg. 1, 2, 3, etc) in python 3.10, Visual Studio 2022. I am receiving this error on os.rename() in the for loop -

> [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk

Here's my whole code -

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import pathlib

window=Tk()
window.title('Hello Python')
window.geometry("300x200+10+10")
window.resizable(False, False)
window.configure(bg='white')

brackets = False

def rename():
    fileNumber = 1
    folderPath = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(parent=window, initialdir='Documents', title='Please select a folder')
    for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):
        fileExt = pathlib.Path(filename).suffix
        filePath = folderPath + '/' + filename
        if (fileExt != '.py') :
            if (brackets):
                os.rename(filePath, str(fileNumber) + ')' + fileExt)
            else:
                os.rename(filePath, str(fileNumber) + fileExt)
            fileNumber += 1

lbl=Label(window, text="Welcome to rename it!", fg='black', bg='white', font=("Helvetica", 20))
lbl.place(relx = 0.5, y = 25, anchor=CENTER)

btn=Button(window, text="Rename", fg='blue', command=rename)
btn.place(x=80, y=100)

window.mainloop()
```

I don't want to move the files, I just want to rename them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing trial and error on this code to find the solution, and this was the problem -

```
os.rename(filePath, str(fileNumber) + fileExt)
```

Suppose this is the path - `D:\file.png` and I want to rename it to `D:\1.png`. In the os.rename command I renamed `D:\file.png` to `1.png`. I forgot the path behind the file, which, in this case, was `D:\`. So the os.rename command needs to be like this -

```
os.rename(filePath, os.path.dirname(filePath) + "//" + str(fileNumber) + fileExt)
```

Answer (score 0):

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116654/14681307

`os.rename` can't move data. It only renames files. in this way, your can't rename a file to another drive.

Moving between drives is copying it first, and then deleting the source file. you can use the `shutil.move()` method which does it when you trying to transfer files between two drives

```py
import shutil
shutil.move(src,dest)
```

Of course, in this case, you do not move files between the drivers, but using shutil may help you

Comment: No, I don't want to move the files, I just want to rename, that's it.

Comment: right, but this error is used for this. Did you use `shuttle`?

Comment: No, I didn't as you can see in the code. I just want to rename using os.rename but it is showing me that error